# Rewriting a Haskell Tree leaves function so that it gives out its computing steps as well as its result

Tags: haskell, tree

I have the task of rewriting two Haskell functions of the Tree Datatype so that they also give out their computing steps.
The Functions are

```
leaves :: Tree a -> [a]
leaves Nil   = []
leaves (Leaf a) = [a]
leaves (Br l r) = leaves l ++ leaves r
```

and

```
leaves'' :: Tree a -> [a]
leaves'' Nil       = []
leaves'' (Leaf a)    = [a]
leaves'' (Br Nil r)   = leaves'' r
leaves'' (Br (Leaf a) r) = a: leaves'' r
leaves'' (Br (Br l' r') r) = leaves'' (Br l' (Br r' r))
```

The Datatype is

```
data Tree a = Leaf a              |
              Br (Tree a) (Tree a)|
              Nil
                deriving Show
```

I don't really even know how to begin

Comment: You can use [**`Debug.Trace`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Debug-Trace.html).

Answer (score 2):

> I don't really even know how to begin

I would start by defining what you mean by "give out their computing steps". Is your program supposed to print some output in a particular format?

The next thing you should do is decide what the new type of `leaves` ought to be. Not knowing the answer to the first question, one possibility is:

```
leaves :: Tree a -> ([ComputingStep], [a])
```

Or maybe you need to return the "steps" interleaved with the leaf elements?:

```
leaves :: Tree a -> [Either ComputingStep a]
```

From here, start with your base cases and go from there. You might like to look at a function like `splitAt` from `Data.List` for inspiration (an example of a recursive function that returns a tuple).

Comment: As far as i understood it, i need the function to give out its normal result and also the number of steps it took for it to terminate/reach this result. Also i think your first type is more correct, as i've been leaning towards something like that too.

Comment: Okay so if you want to output _number of steps_ then an appropriate type would probably be: `Tree a -> (Int, [a])`

Comment: Yeah, that seems right, and having the steps as output for an empty list and just one Leaf should be easy, because, as far as i understood it, they should both be one so all i gotta do is change them to  ([], 1) and ([a],1) , but i'm having trouble doing the last part, leaves l ++ leaves r, as i still need to find out exactly how long that would take and how to fit the types correctly

Comment: Please take a look at `splitAt` as I suggested. I think you can figure it out. You're trying to translate the following into code: "`leaves` of a branch is (the sum of the steps for the right and left branches, the concatenation of the leaves for the right and left branches)". You'll want to do: `let (stepsLeft, leavesLeft) = leaves l ... in ...`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but i keep getting the same type errors and i still don't know how long it takes for the function to terminate all before i even made it to the second function, so i think i'm gonna give up. Maybe its because i missed a bunch of lectures recently or maybe i'm just not cut out for Computer science. Still thank you though you've helped a lot.

Answer (score -1):

From comments I guessed you only need information how many function calls did you make. You may just sum them in pretty simple way:

```
leaves :: Tree a -> (Int, [a])
leaves''' Nil = (1, [])
leaves''' (Leaf a) = (1, [a])
leaves''' (Br l r) = let (n1, resl) = leaves''' l
                         (n2, resr) = leaves''' r
                     in (n1 + n2 + 1, resl ++ resr)
```

(and second variant in similar way)

Comment: If you use an accumulator in `go`, why do you fall back to calling `leaves` in the `Br` case?

Comment: @gallais My God, my mistake. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: I'm still not sure what the point of the accumulator is: you could simply have `(1, [])` and `(1, [a])` in the base cases and `(n1 + n2 + 1, resl ++ resr)` in the branch case.

Comment: Yes, it is not necessary, I'm just much more used to this style. I will rewrite my answer because in this case it is overkill